# fdisk fsync io error

Tags: partition, fdisk

I have a 32 GB sony pen drive. I am getting error while writing/formatting it as:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 28.93 GiB, 31037849600 bytes, 60620800 sectors
Disk model: Storage Media   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6ae77cd9

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 41945087 41943040  20G 83 Linux

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
/dev/sdb: fsync device failed: Input/output error
```

Whats going on here?

Comment: In my life I've seen flash drives whose partition table cannot be edited. I'm not sure if that's the case here.

Comment: Check `dmesg` to see if it says anything else about `/dev/sdb`.